# Obtaining the index of a specific sheet "Sheet_name" using jxl

Tags: java, jxl

Is there a way to get the index of a specific sheet "Sheet_name" using jxl?

And what does the getSheet(String name) function of jxl library do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: getsheet - Gets the sheet with the specified name from within the same workbook. Check http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there isn't.

A very simple solution would be:

```
final String sheetName = "somesheet";
Integer index = null;
final Sheet[] sheets = workbook.getSheets();            
for(int i=0;i<sheets.length && index == null; i++) {
    if(sheets[i].getName().equals(sheetName)) {
        index = i;                  
    }
}
```